# MongoDB aggregate pipeline - which step removed the last document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assume a simple setup where the MongoDB aggregation pipeline consists of two basic steps:

1. match the wanted documents ($match)
2. check permisssions to the documents ($redact)

This can be done like

```
db.thingies.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { SOME_CONDITION } },
     { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { SOME_PERMISSION_CHECK },
           then: "$$KEEP",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
);
```

Now imagine that you execute this 2 stage pipeline and the result is empty. Is there any way to determine whether this was:

- a 404: NOT-FOUND (the $match result was emty?), or
- a 403: FORBIDDEN (the $redact result was empty)

In short, was the empty result reached in stage 1 or was it reached in stage 2?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here and at best you are essentially asking for "opinions", which is off-topic and won't get you quality answers ( if any ).Instead of the theoretical premise, why don't you actually show people what you are trying to achieve and then we can actually give you a a factual answer on how to get that done. As it stands the question has too many generalizations. If you want to handle "object level permissions", then actually "show us" what needs to happen and what sort of data needs to be inspected. The data is the main thing.

Comment: @Iwallent, you need to define what is meant by `SOME_PERMISSION_CHECK`, and provide your `data set`

Comment: @NeilLunn I honestly do not feel the question is too general. I have edited it a bit, but I am basically just asking if there is any way to determine whether the pipeline is empty prior to stage 2. $match is followed by $redact. Can one tell if the result is empty before the $redact stage is reached? I have removed the last question that was correctly asking for opinions. The actual condition/check is not important to what I am asking.

Comment: Basically asking? Then NOT the way that you think you do it then. But if you want a real answer then you need to show a real document with an expected outcome. That is actually expected of your questions here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW, we honestly disagree, which is why you are attracting close votes, and why you get asked to clarify these things before your question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three answers, because it's a little unclear what you're asking:

1: If you're running the aggregation within your program, and you want your program to immediately know why the aggregation had an empty output, then the answer is no: the aggregation doesn't return that information, and the server doesn't store it. Your program may need to run further queries to interrogate the data to find out what further action to take.

2: If you're asking for a retrospective analysis of why *a particular run of an aggregation, at a particular date and time* came up with its output, then no: there's no way of knowing for sure. What you'd need is a log of all the stages of the aggregation, *with the complete resultset at the end of each stage*; and MongoDB doesn't do that kind of logging (it would be very verbose, and difficult to manage).

3: If you need a retrospective analysis of why a particular run of an aggregation came up with its output, and you're willing and able to manually reconstruct the data as necessary and manually re-run the query, then debugging it to find the effects of each stage is fairly straightforward : just comment out all the stages except the first, and run the aggregation:

```
db.thingies.aggregate([
    { $match: { SOME_CONDITION } },
    // { $redact: { $cond: { if: { SOME_PERMISSION_CHECK }, then: "$$KEEP", else: "$$PRUNE" } } }
]);
```

Analyse the output from that aggregation; if it seems OK then uncomment the next stage, run the aggregation, and analyse the output - keep going until you've found which stage has the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your straight well balanced answer. I guess I had hoped for an answer that introduced some intermediate stages that collected the needed $count and added a reason based on $bucket or something crazy like that. But sometimes a straight 'no' is the right answer. Again, thanks for your attitude, much appreciated!